# Capturing regexp which excludes two literals

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot

In a Spring controller I want an `updateuser` endpoint, a `deleteuser` endpoint and a generic one that captures the rest of options:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{action:^((?!(updateuser|deleteuser)).)+}")
// Do something depending on `action`, need to capture the match

@PostMapping(value = "/updateuser")
// Update user

@PostMapping(value = "/deleteuser")
// Delete user
```

Using that regexp throws:

> The number of capturing groups in the pattern segment
> (^((?!updateuser|deleteuser).)*) does not match the number of URI
> template variables it defines, which can occur if capturing groups are
> used in a URI template regex. Use non-capturing groups instead.

I have no problem if I use `@PostMapping(value = "/{action:^.*(?!updateuser)}")`

Which would be the correct regexp?

Comment: Try `^(?:(?!(?:update|delete)user).)+$` or `^(?!.*(?:update|delete)user).+$`

Comment: `^(?!.*(?:update|delete)user).+$` worked, thanks! If you put in an answer I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the updateuser and deleteuser by using a single negative lookahead without a capture group, instead of using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach matching a single character followed by the assertion.

```
^(?!.*(?:update|delete)user).+$
```

If it should be more strict, you can use word boundaries to prevent partial word matches:

```
^(?!.*\b(?:update|delete)user\b).+$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gvP2HW/1).